# AWS S3 make folder IFA forever

Tags: amazon-s3

In aws s3 web interface we can select a specific folder then navigate to properties and select IFA... like this

[image]

This will start processing all existing data, but if you open the same properties page again its not selected. If you select again and apply it will show a processing bar again...

**Its ambiguous does that folder remain IFA once selected and saved? will future uploads to that folder stored in IFA storage? If not how do we do that?**

I know that there is migration rule like after 30 days move to IFA but i know upfront that my data is suitable for IFA storage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For all selected items" means the *current objects*, not the folders.

The folders do not exist in S3 in any meaningful sense yes, you can "create" a folder but all that does is create a placeholder for convenience in the console -- there are never any files actually "in" the folder -- so it is impossible to actually set any kind of properties on them.  The folders that appear in the console are just a human-friendly representation of a hierarchy, created by splitting the keys on `/` delimiters.

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, where objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

If you want objects stored for their lifetime as either `STANDARD_IA` or `REDUCED_REDUNDANCY` then you have to initially upload them that way.  If you want them to transition to `STANDARD_IA` or `GLACIER`  later, then you use lifecycle policies.

Note also that changing storage classes in the console like you are doing incurs the same cost as re-uploading the object, because changing storage classes is accomplished by the console invoking the S3 copy operation -- using the same key for source and destination. It's $0.01 per 1000 objects, so use it wisely on large collections of objects.  Objects and their metadata are immutable, so modifying them (including storage class, which isn't technically metadata) requires replacing the object with an identical object.

Comment: Quick question, i've been using TransferManager (java) to upload files, but i cant find any api to tell it that i want them to go to IFA storage... is there anything i miss here? maybe i shall use some other api to upload?

Comment: oh found it : PutObjectRequest -> setStorageClass(StandardInfrequentAccess.toString());